# Output of nn.Linear is different for the same input

Tags: python, pytorch

In `torch==1.7.1+cu101`, I have two tensors

```
import torch
a = torch.rand(1,5,10)
b = torch.rand(100,1,10)
```

and a feed-forward network

```
import torch.nn as nn
l = nn.Linear(10,10)
```

I force one row of them to be equal:

```
a[0,0] = b[80][0].clone()
```

Then I feed both tensors to `l`:

```
r1 = l(a)
r2 = l(b)
```

Apparently, since `a[0,0]` is equal to `b[80,0]`, `r1[0,0]` **must be equal to** `r2[80,0]`.
But it turns out to be like:

```
(r1[0,0] == r2[80,0]).all()
>>> False
```

I've fixed the randomness by:

```
seed = 42

random.seed(seed)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
```

Does anyone know why `(r1[0,0] == r2[80,0]).all()` is False?

Comment: The result you got is not reproducible, it returned `tensor(True)` on my end.

Comment: @Ivan I was able to reproduce it

Comment: @Ivan I'm using `torch==1.7.1+cu101`

Comment: Did you have a look at `r1[0,0]` and `r2[80,0]`?

Comment: output `tensor(True)` for `r1[0,0] == r2[80,0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to print `r1[0, 0]` and `r2[80, 0]`, you'd see that they are extremely similar. Even identical within the number of printed digits.

However, if you print `r1[0, 0] - r2[80, 0]` you'll see that the resulting entries are not perfectly `0.0` (though they are close to it), meaning that `r1[0, 0]` and `r2[80, 0]` are close but not perfectly identical.

Now, if we were to do take those individual vectors out first, and then pass them through the linear layer like this:

```py
r1_small = l(a[0, 0])
r2_small = l(b[80, 0])
print((r1_small == r2_small).all())  # tensor(True)
```

we get that they are perfectly identical, even despite being floats.

So, that means that some difference is introduced by the identical vectors being smaller **parts of bigger tensors when they are passed through the linear layer**.

It's also very much worth noting that the same difference does not arise when the first n-1 dimensions are all powers of 2:

```py
a2 = torch.randn(8, 8, 10)
b2 = torch.randn(4, 16, 10)
a2[0, 0] = b2[1, 0].clone()
r1_2 = l(a2)
r2_2 = l(b2)
print((r1_2[0, 0] == r2_2[1, 0]).all())  # tensor(True)
```

So, while I don't know the details, I suspect it has to do with [byte alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846914/what-is-meant-by-memory-is-8-bytes-aligned).

In general, testing for perfect equality between float values that should be mathematically equal will not always give the expected results. So how do we handle these differences? You can use [torch.isclose](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isclose.html) or [torch.allclose](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.allclose.html) to check for imperfect equality.

Comment: checked the value in `r1[0,0]` and `r2[80,0]`, found they are quite equal in the first 5 digits. I attribute the difference to saving strategy for float number or something else. BTW, I wonder if this 'inequality' would affect the final result of deep learning models?

Comment: Check out this conversation: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-debug-with-floating-point-differences/82397