# Why is the difference between id(2) and id(1) equal to 32?

Tags: python, python-internals

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> id(a), id(b), id(b) - id(a)
(1814458401008, 1814458401040, 32)
```

Is the memory address returned by `id` in bits or in bytes? Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_FromLong):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all
> integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you
> actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

If integers were 32 bits and the numbers -5 to 256 were stored close together in memory, then the numbers 1 and 2 would be 32 bits apart.

However, the size of a number object is 28 bytes.

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = 1
>>> a.__sizeof__(), sys.getsizeof(a), sys.getsizeof(3)
(28, 28, 28)
```

If id returns an address in bytes, what is the 32-28=4 bytes between 1 and 2 for?

For bigger numbers, the addresses are random which makes sense:

```
>>> a = 257
>>> b = 258
>>> id(a), id(b), id(b) - id(a)
(1814557834096, 1814557827568, -6528)
```

Comment: What makes you think `id` returns a memory address?

Comment: @Barmar: for CPython that's [actually documented as an implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

Comment: All objects in a 64-bit computer need to be on 8 byte boundaries, for maximum efficiency in accessing them.  28 isn't a multiple of 8, so it gets rounded up to 32.

Comment: @jasonharper Multiple of 16.

Comment: I'm not really sure `sys.getsizeof(a)` return the size of the "number" but just the object (PyLongObject) that stores the number object.

Comment: @Corralien That "just" sounds like you have it backwards. The object is bigger than just its digits (I assume that's what you mean with "number").

Comment: @jasonharper [Demo](https://tio.run/##LcxBCsIwFIThfU4xG2kCVVqEIkIXnkNEUvOqT9I0JEHa08dU/BezGj6/ptfsjicfcmb06IQue90zxjngDnYI2j1Jts0vdRM@sEvSkpORkpy0l2xqaKVUjcrwOFIglzAPb3qkeKiU2Khlo/RZoKRjpJDARi4KO7Qd@h7NH64u1kIbE6i8Igx/OPJgCcNanoXL@Qs).

Comment: @KellyBundy. Yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jasonharper answered in a comment, it's to make the address 8 bytes aligned. For more details, go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846925/20898396) answer.